# Powershell indicating WinRm not running when it is

Tags: powershell

I have a script that builds a VM and installs multiple programs. The script runs on a separate server, and builds the VM by using Invoke-Command to execute commands remotely on the VM server. There are perhaps 20 steps to the process, with each step creating a session, invoking a command on the VM, then removing the session.

Towards the end of the script I'm always getting the error below, but not always on the same step. When I run the script again leaving off where it last failed, it works fine. Obviously Winrm is enabled so I'm at a loss as to what can be causing it.

What possible reasons could explain getting this error when WinRM is most definitely running?

"Processing data for a remote command failed with the following error message:  The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request.  Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM.  If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic."

Comment: What steps precede the fails? Perhaps you are invoking something which affects WinRM or simply hogs all the resources on your VM so it cannot respond in a timely manner.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the 'Web Management Service' is not running on the remote machine.
This service is required for IIS management and some applications.

Regards